# 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'get_worksheet_by_name'

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter as xl
wb = xl.Workbook(f, {'in_memory': True})
sheet = wb.add_worksheet('example')
sheet = wb.get_worksheet_by_name('example')
```

According to the [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-get-worksheet-by-name) the function is correct but I get an error.

Comment: what happens if you create the workbook in a temp directory instead (omitting the `'in_memory': True` parameter)

Comment: I would guess that you don't have the latest version of the module where that method was added. What is the output of `python -c 'import xlsxwriter; print(xlsxwriter.__version__)'` It should be >= 0.8.7

Answer (score 1):

I was using an old version of xlsxwriter.That method did not exist with the old version. Updating the module solves the issue. In my case I only had to add the new version to requirements.txt and run the second command becuase I'm using virtualenv. Don't use sudo if your using a virtual environment.

```
pip install xlsxwriter --upgrade


pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```